# Color row background by its value

Tags: php, uitableview, background-color

I am looking to change a row color by depending its value on status column,
(there will be one ofe these 3 words on status like: "Ordered", "shipped", "completed")

This is what i made from scratch codes i found online

here is my code:

```
    <div class="tabela">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="order_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID.</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Shipping</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
     <tfoot>
      <tr>
          <th colspan="9"><b>Total</b></th>
       <th id="total_order"></th>
      </tr>
     </tfoot>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
   </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
   var dataTable = $('#order_data').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
     url:"template/fetch.php",
     type:"POST" 
    },
    drawCallback:function(settings)
    {
     $('#total_order').html(settings.json.total);
    },

   });
   });
</script>
```

Also here it is my Fetch:

```
<?php

//fetch.php

// Include config file
require_once "../config/configpdo.php";


$column = array('order_id', 'order_date', 'order_customer_name', 'order_item', 'order_address', 'order_city', 'order_number', 'order_value', 'order_ship', 'order_status');

$query = '
SELECT * FROM tbl_order 
WHERE order_id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_date LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_customer_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_item LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
OR order_address LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
OR order_city LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
OR order_value LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
OR order_ship LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
OR order_number LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
OR order_status LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"

';

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY order_id DESC ';
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $connect->prepare($query . $query1);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

$data = array();

$total_order = 0;

foreach($result as $row)
{
$sub_array = array();
$sub_array[] = $row["order_id"];
$sub_array[] = $row["order_date"];
$sub_array[] = $row["order_customer_name"];
$sub_array[] = $row["order_item"];
$sub_array[] = $row["order_address"];
$sub_array[] = $row["order_city"];
$sub_array[] = $row["order_number"];
$sub_array[] = $row["order_status"];
$sub_array[] = $row["order_ship"];
$sub_array[] = $row["order_value"]; 
 $total_order = $total_order + floatval($row["order_value"]);
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function count_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_order";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
 'draw'    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 'recordsTotal'  => count_all_data($connect),
 'recordsFiltered' => $number_filter_row,
 'data'    => $data,
 'total'    => number_format($total_order, 2)
);

echo json_encode($output);


?>
```

I can imagine this can be so easy for some one but very hard for me as a beginer.
Will aprichiate if someone will help me on this issue

Answer (score 0):

I thank you for nobodys help, so strugelyng for days on forumes i made a solution from scratches. There were an idea by targeting rows and frocing the rows to insert a class if a specific word is founded and i niserted a function above the script:

```
   rowCallback: function( row, data, index ) {
if ( data[7] == "Ordered" ) {$(row).addClass('green');} 
else if ( data[7] == "Shipped" ) {$(row).addClass('orange');}
else if ( data[7] == "Completed" ) {$(row).addClass('red');}
```

}

also had to make css styles by inserting like this one on inside the ....

```
<style>
.green{
background-color:#85e085 !important;}
.orange{
background-color:#ffb366 !important;}
.red{
background-color:#ff6666 !important;
}
</style>
```

I am posting the answer maybe someone is having same issue and it can help a little.
if you need anything that belong to this one let me know...